# "sowohl ... als auch" auf Position 1

Tags: grammaticality, conjunction

Viele Grammatikbücher sagen, dass die Doppelkonjunktion "sowohl ... als auch" *normalerweise* im Mittelfeld stehen soll. Ich finde aber die folgenden Formulierungen nicht verkehrt:

> Sowohl meine Schwester als auch ich ( = wir ) können fünf Sprachen sprechen.
>
> Sowohl am Samstag als auch am Sonntag ( = am Wochenende ) sind wir schwimmen gegangen.

Die folgenden Sätze finde ich aber ungeschickt:

> Sowohl Äpfel als auch Orangen habe ich gekauft.
>
> Sowohl freundlich als auch hilfsbereit ist er.

Wie gebräuchlich ist es die Doppelkonjunktion "sowohl ... als auch" auf Position 1 zu bringen? Gibt es dafür eine feste Regel? Wenn nicht, wann kann man "sowohl ... als auch" auf erster Position schreiben?

Comment: Ich habe keine Quellen, ich denke: es ist von der gewünschten Betonung abhängig. Statt "Meine Schwester *und* ich können..." eben das "*sowohl als auch*". Somit finde ich das erste "ungeschickte" Beispiel keineswegs ungeschickt, im Gesprochenen würde ich die Betonung so wählen, dass die Besonderheit in den Äpfeln & Orangen liegt. Und *normalerweise* ist schon ein Hinweis, dass es auch an anderer Stelle passen kann.

Comment: Deine Beispiele sind definitiv nicht falsch. Dennoch klingen die letzten beiden Sätze, die du ungeschickt findest, wirklich nicht gut. Ob es eine Regel gibt, weiß ich nicht, aber vom Sprachgefühl her liegst du völlig richtig!

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: "Meine Schwester und ich können 5 Sprachen" könnte auch heißen, dass die beiden zusammen 5 Sprachen können, also jeder je 3 mit Überlappung zum Beispiel. Die Alternative war aber eh "Fünf Sprachen können sowohl meine Schwester, als auch ich, sprechen."

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, die Grammatikbücher meinen etwas anderes. Im Beispiel

> *Sowohl meine Schwester als auch ich* **können** fünf Sprachen sprechen.

steht nicht *sowohl* an Position 1, sondern die Konjunktion *sowohl … als auch* mit den Satzgliedern, die sie verbindet: *meine Schwester*, *ich*.

Ein Beispiel für einen Konnektor auf Position 1 wäre dagegen:

> *Weder* **spricht** sie, *noch* **wird** sie angesprochen.

Und so scheinen Sprecher *sowohl … als auch* tatsächlich nicht gerne zu benutzen. Man findet nur wenige Beispiele, zum Beispiel in einer Übersetzung von Platos *Staat*:

> Ja, erwiederte ich, *sowohl* **gibt** es ein Höheres, *als auch* **soll** man von eben jenen nicht bloß einen Umriß betrachten […] ([Link](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/platon/staat/staat063.html))

Oder aus einem Forenbeitrag:

> *Sowohl* **hat** er dich in dieser Zeit nicht geschätzt und geliebt, *als auch* **hat** er der A[ffären]F[rau] etwas erzählt um sein Ziel zu erreichen.

Ich finde die Beispiele so marginal, daß ich dem Grammatikbuch einfach recht geben würde.

Answer (score 1):

Die einzige Regel, die man nicht umwerfen kann, ist daß das konjugierte Verb auf Position 2 stehen muß. (Im Hauptsatz.) Ansonsten kann man die Satzelemente herumschieben, zwar nicht lustig drauflos, wie man sie braucht. Sprich man muß einen Grund haben, diese aus ihrer üblichen Position herauszubewegen. Meist gelten Elemente die nach vorne gebracht werden als akzentuiert.

Insofern sind die letzten zwei Beispiele grammatikalisch vollkommen korrekt. Es wird aber betont, daß ich beides (Orangen und Äpfel) gekauft habe und es ist weniger wichtig was ich gemacht habe (gekauft) und wer (ich) das gemacht hat.